# identical strings. one is misbehaving

Tags: c

**v** is read from stdin
**v2** is not but they are identical.

```
char *v;
v = (char *) malloc(1);
fread(v,i,1,stdin);
printf("%s",v);
```

prints:

```
a=aaa&b=ooo%3C%2Ftest%3Eooo
```

**v2** is identical to **v**

```
char *v2 = "a=aaa&b=ooo%3C%2Ftest%3Eooo"
```

let's try to **PARSE** what is after "**b=**" from "**v**"

```
const char *PATTERN1 = "b=";
const char *PATTERN2 = "&";

char *END = NULL;
char *START = strstr(v, PATTERN1);

if (START) {
START = START + strlen(PATTERN1);
char * END = strstr(START, PATTERN2);

if (!END){
ENDm = START + strlen(START);
}

TARGET = malloc(END - START + 1);
memcpy(TARGET, START, END - START);
TARGET[END - START] = '\0';
}

printf("--%s--",TARGET);
```

result :

```
--abc%3C%2Ftest%!--
```

it is missing some stuff towards the end.  ( also has an extra "!" )

Now let's use the same code above on "**v2**"

```
--abc%3C%2Ftest%3Eabc--
```

this time nothing is missing

Comment: `v = (char *) malloc(1);` how do you expect this to accomodate your whole string?

Comment: what should it have been ? I was suspecting something like that but I dont know much about those things yet.

Comment: use malloc with bigger size. v = malloc(100) should be enough in your case

Comment: Usualy the [`man page of the command you are using fread`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) is a good bet on how to get the length.

Comment: **v = (char *) malloc(100);** worked.

Comment: Note that it is [redundant and potentially dangerous to cast the result of malloc and friends in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/253056).

Comment: Als, please do not use ALL UPPER CASE VARIABLE NAMES - this is C, not FORTRAN or BASIC.

Comment: @PaulR It is a common naming convention in C to name constants with all upper case.

Comment: @Lundin: yes, I'm aware of that, but the OP seems to using all upper case for local variables, e.g. `START`, `END`, `TARGET`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot store a string in an array of 1 characters. The only string you can store is `""` (the empty string) since that requires exactly one character for the `'\0'` terminator.

Your code suffers from undefined behavior, so it cannot be reasoned about beyond that.